# How to add and remove linear layout by button click

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to use two buttons to dynamically add and remove linear layout.

```
    protected void createT () {
    // -----------------------------------------------
    count++;
    LinearLayout temp_ll, frame;
    frame = new LinearLayout(this);
    frame.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    frame.setId(count);
    EditText temp1, temp2;

    for (int i=0; i<numClass; i++) {

        temp_ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        temp_ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        temp1 = new EditText(this);
        temp2 = new EditText(this);
        temp2.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
        temp1.setHint("class name");
        temp2.setHint("grade");

        temp_ll.addView(temp1);
        temp_ll.addView(temp2);
        frame.addView(temp_ll);
    }

    ll.addView(frame);
}

protected void deleteT() {
    // --------------------------------------
    if (count > 0) {
                    LinearLayout temp = new LinearLyout(this);
        temp = (LinearLayout) findViewById(count);
        temp.removeAllViews();
        temp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        count--;
    }
}
```

- Every time I press **add** button, it calls the `createT()`
- Every time i press **del** button it calls the `deleteT()`

The problem is that I'm using **count** variable to keep track of `linearLayout` IDs.
First time when I press **add** button **x** times and then press **del** button everything is fine.

THE PROBLEM IS THAT AFTER PRESSING **ADD** SECOND TIME .

Comment: no error, just the "del" button does not respond after the first time

Comment: want to delete LinearLayout or any specific one ... form up or down ?

Comment: Can I just know what is the reason u r trying this? So that someone might help you if there is also an easy way to achieve ur target.

Comment: the idea is to press "add" button and create linear layout in order to add some textViews, EditTexts later. And "del" button to delete that specific linear layout (and hopefully all objects in it). The "count" is used to set ID to a linearLayout and also to find it in order to delete

Comment: This is for Dheeresh Singh.... from down to up

Comment: What is numClass field for inside the for statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked your code and I found a little mistake inside the deleteT() method, you remove all view inside the LinearLayout, but you didn't remove the actual layout from the root layout.

And an another suggestion, you don't need a new LinearLayout instance when you want to use findviewbyid method, and use ll.removeView(View) method to delete the dynamic LinearLayout container.

Here is the code:

```
private int count;
private LinearLayout ll;
private final int numClass = 1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_linearlayout);
}

public void createT(View view) {
    count++;
    final LinearLayout frame = new LinearLayout(this);
    frame.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    frame.setId(count);

    for (int i = 0; i < numClass; i++) {
        final LinearLayout temp_ll = new LinearLayout(this);

        final EditText temp1;
        final EditText temp2;
        temp_ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        temp1 = new EditText(this);
        temp2 = new EditText(this);
        temp2.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
        temp1.setHint("class name");
        temp2.setHint("grade");

        temp_ll.addView(temp1);
        temp_ll.addView(temp2);
        frame.addView(temp_ll);
    }
    ll.addView(frame);

}

public void deleteT(View view) {
    if (count > 0) {
        final LinearLayout temp = (LinearLayout) ll.findViewById(count);
        temp.removeAllViews();
        ll.removeView(temp);
        count--;
    }
}
```

And the layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/main_linearlayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="add"
        android:onClick="createT" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="delete"
        android:onClick="deleteT" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: if you check my code above there is a line:
{ temp.setVisibility(View.GONE); } --- this removes the root layout.

I had that code without that line you mentioned, and it was not working

Comment: You can't remove the view with View.GONE the layout is still in place under the parent view only non-visible (hide from the parent view) and the id is in use. I created a sample app with your code and it works perfetly with removeView() method. For more information please read the [View reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) and check the setVisibility() method and the parameters VISIBLE, GONE and INVIIBLE.

Comment: I updated my answer so you can check the class and the layout xml too.

Comment: Thanks a lot. ll.removeView(temp) did it